# How to verify that element is link or not in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to check whether the given element is link or not and how to perform the operations(element is displayed or enable) on the element?

```
link=driver.find_element_by_id("btn-baseFooter-termsOfUse") #element 
    if link.tag_name=='a': #validating the element 
        print('element is link')
    else:
        print('element is text')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def TermAndPrivacyPolicy(self):
    sleep(10)
    terms=driver.find_element(By.ID, "btn-baseFooter-termsOfUse")
    if terms.tag_name == 'a':
        print('element is: ',terms.tag_name)
    else:
        print('element is not link it is: ',terms.tag_name)

    if terms.is_displayed() and terms.is_enabled()==True:
        terms.click()
        print(terms.'link is enabled, displayed and link is clicked')
        sleep(2)
        element=driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btn-termsConditions-close')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        element.click()
    else:
        print('Link is neither enable or displayed')
```